# Picasa getAlbum request not working Android

Tags: java, android, http, google-api, picasa

```
String album = "http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/"+email;
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(albumUrl).openConnection();

  // request method, timeout and headers
  con.setRequestMethod("GET") ;
  con.setReadTimeout(15000);
  con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth="+auth);
  con.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "2");

  // set timeout and that we will process output
  con.setReadTimeout(15000);
  con.setDoOutput(true);

  // connnect to url
  con.connect();

  // read output returned for url
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
```

**Problem :** Everytime i call **con.getInputStream()** it gives me **file not found exception.**
But when i load the same url in the **desktop browser** then it is displaying correct data.

I am confused why on **android** it is throwing exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your LogCat errors.

Comment: AlbumList.fetchAlbumList()415
02-19 18:14:22.159: W/System.err(1507): java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/honeysaini88
02-19 18:14:22.159: W/System.err(1507):  at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:186)
02-19 18:14:22.159: W/System.err(1507):  at com.example.picasa.AlbumList.fetchAlbumList(AlbumList.java:124)
02-19 18:14:22.169: W/System.err(1507):  at com.example.picasa.MainActivity$1.run(MainActivity.java:35)
02-19 18:14:22.169: W/System.err(1507):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

Comment: Honestly I don't see the problem yet... Please click "[edit]" and post all of the LogCat errors in your question, it looks like some may be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this?  Maybe you just missed the https

below example uses *default* for authenticated user and the experimental fields list.

```
url = "https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default?kind=album&access=public&fields="
                + URLEncoder
                        .encode("entry(title,id,gphoto:numphotosremaining,gphoto:numphotos,media:group/media:thumbnail)",
                                "UTF-8");
```

https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol#ListAlbums